# Create Table from inner join extremely slow

Tags: mysql, linux, performance, join

I have a statement as below

```
CREATE TABLE INPUT_OUTPUT 
SELECT T1_C1,.....,T1_C300, T1_PID from T1 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT T2_C1,T2_C2,T2_PID FROM T2) as RESPONSE ON T1.T1_PID=RESPONSE.T2_PID
```

which is running extremely slow -  for 5 hours now. The two tables have about 4 million rows and a few hundred columns.

I have an 8-core, 64gb ram ubuntu-linux machine and using top I can see that not even 3gb is being used by the mysql process on just one core, although admittedly it's usage is consistently at 100%. It's upsetting that not all cores are being used.

I want to create the table much faster than this.

Should I use

```
CREATE TABLE INPUT_OUTPUT LIKE T1
```

alter INPUT_OUTPUT by adding the extra columns for those relevant in T2 and then populate it? I'm not sure of the syntax to do it and whether it will lead to a speed up.

Comment: I'm confused: the subquery doesn't have a PID column.

Comment: HPC has nothing to do with slow SQL queries - removed HPC tag.

Answer (score 0):

Does `T1_PID` have an index?  If so, this should run quickly.  Run an `EXPLAIN` of the `SELECT` part of your query and see what it says.

That said, I don't understand why you need the subquery.  What is wrong with:

```
CREATE TABLE INPUT_OUTPUT 
SELECT T1_C1,.....,T1_C300, T1_PID, T2_C1, T2_C2, T2_PID
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.T1_PID=T2.T2_PID
```

Using the latter should work if *either* `T1` or `T2` has a `PID` index.

Comment: Thanks for the index commment, I'll try it. It seems like I just need a    CREATE INDEX PID on T1 (T1_PID) .My tables are so huge and I'll be looking them up (hopefully loading them into memory) using R. I want to just join on the necessary parts of T1 and T2.